# To connect a Samsung 10.1 Tab, Model GT-P 7500 to the Ethernet

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have purchased a BobjGear USB to RJ45 Compact Fast Ethernet Adapter made for Android Tablets, as well as a I-Tech USB 2.0 Fast Ethernet Adapter.

I also purchased an Adapter Cable OTG for the Samsung Galaxy TAB Android 10.1, GT-P 7500.

Both USB Ethernet Adapters come with a Driver (CD)

I have installed the Drivers to my PC Windows 7 and also installed the Drivers to my wifes MAC.

QUESTION IS: HOW DO I INSTALL THE DRIVERS ON MY TAB ? As it seems that I need the Driver in order to make it work.

Is there anyone out there who can help me  ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)